# about file sharing in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

i saw one application in App store.(files lite by olive toast). inwhich they have used
web server(webDAV url) to transfer file from PC to ipod or iphone and also another option bonjour.how can i use bonjour (what is it ?)..how can i do for my application?
internally how they have done?any help please?

Answer (score 2):

Bonjour is Apple's "Zero-configuration networking". Essentially it allows you to advertise a service on the network by name, allowing other machines on the local network to discover it. There's plenty of high quality documentation available from Apple. Just google it.

Bonjour is just a way for your desktop application to discover the ip address of the iPhone. To actually transfer data to or from your device, you need to write that code yourself. Unfortunately Apple doesn't provide a framework to do this.

Some people use WebDAV, implemented with an open source framework.

Another option is to use ZSync, if you are using Core Data:

http://www.zarrastudios.com/ZSync/ZSync.html